# Problem using subjunctive mood in different tenses

Tags: verbs, subjunctive-mood, tenses

How are these sentences translated this in Italian? I am having problem using the *congiuntivo*.

> If I had asked it later, she wouldn't have accepted it.
>
> If I had her number I would call her.
>
> If I had had her number I would have called her.

Comment: I took the liberty to improve the formatting and presentation. Feel free to revert if you think it changes the meaning of your question (also the Italian *modo congiuntivo* is called *subjunctive mood* in English)

Comment: Also, are you sure that your first sentence is correct (in English)? I was taught that you are not supposed to use *would* in the if clause. I'm not a native speaker,  but *If I had asked it her later, she wouldn't have accepted* sounds way more natural to me.

Comment: Thank you Denis, I haven't received the modification notification,  are you a native English speaker? Shall you tell me what to say instead of the first sentence to avoid using would in an if clause?

Comment: I am not a native English speaker, although I have been living for some time in the US. According to [this website](http://www.ef.edu/english-resources/english-grammar/conditional/) the correct form is *If I had asked it later, she wouldn't have accepted*.

Comment: I think you are right Denis

Comment: @Denis Different groups of English speakers say such things either way. I wouldn't go so far as to say one is *wrong*.

Answer (score 12):

I would translate the example sentences as follows:

> Se l'avessi chiesto dopo, non avrebbe accettato
>
> Se avessi il suo numero, la chiamerei
>
> Se avessi avuto il suo numero, l'avrei chiamata

This kind of sentences are called *periodi ipotetici* (hypotetical sentences) in Italian. An exposition of the rules about them can be found [here](http://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/periodo-ipotetico_%28La-grammatica-italiana%29/). Let me briefly summarize them for you in your examples.

#### If I had asked it later, she wouldn't have accepted

In English, this is what's called a *type 3* conditional sentence, because it describes an unreal past condition and its probable result in the past. In Italian the corresponding version is a *periodo ipotetico dell'irrealtà* (unreal hypotetical sentece), in the past form. It requires the if clause (*protasi* in Italian) at the *congiuntivo trapassato* and the main clause (*apodosi* in Italian) at the *condizionale passato*. So

> Se l'avessi chiesto dopo, non avrebbe accettato

#### If I had her number, I would call her

In English this is a *type 2* conditional sentence, because it describes an hypothetical condition, and its probable result. The corresponding Italian version is the *periodo ipotetico della possibilità*. It requires the if clause at the *congiuntivo imperfetto* and the main clause at the *condizionale presente* or *imperativo*. So

> Se avessi il suo numero, la chiamerei

#### If I had had her number, I would have called her

This is again a type 3 conditional sentence. As such, it is translated with a *periodo ipotetico dell'irrealtà*, set in the past.

> Se avessi avuto il suo numero, l'avrei chiamata

To summarize

```
 Type of periodo ipotetico | If clause (protasi)     | Main clause (apodosi)
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   Realtà                  | Indicativo              | Indicativo/Imperativo
   (the hypothesis is      |                         |
    certain or very        |                         |
    likely)                |                         |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   Possibilità             | Congiuntivo imperfetto  | Condizionale presente/
   (the hypothesis is      |                         | Imperativo
    possible but not       |                         |
    certain)               |                         | 
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    Irrealtà, I            | Congiuntivo imperfetto  | Condizionale presente/
    (the hypothesis is     |                         | Imperativo
     impossible and set    |                         |
     in the present)       |                         |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    Irrealtà, II           | Congiuntivo trapassato  | Condizionale passato
    (the hypothesis is     |                         | 
     impossible and set    |                         |
     in the past)          |                         |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

By the way, I never really understood the difference between *Possibilità* and *Irrealtà I*. Thankfully they have the same tenses, so I can happily ignore their distinction. Note that in English they are both conflated into a type 2 conditional clause.