# Uso del congiuntivo in una frase

Tags: verbs

Quale delle due è corretta: "se non sto parlando con qualcun altro, sembra che l'abbia scritto bene il tuo numero alla fine" o "sembra che l'avessi scritto bene"?

Comment: La mia risposta a questa domanda potrebbe essere d'aiuto: https://italian.stackexchange.com/questions/8163/problem-using-subjunctive-mood-in-different-tenses/8164#8164

Answer (score 2, accepted):

È corretta la prima. Nella principale c'è un verbo al presente indicativo, la relazione tra principale e subordinata è di anteriorità ("sembra" ora che "ho scritto bene" prima) e nella subordinata l'azione è compiuta (all'indicativo si direbbe con il passato prossimo).

Comment: E se dicessi ad esempio " sembra che tu avessi ragione a riguardo" sarebbe sbagliato? se no, perchè?

Comment: Non è sbagliato. In frasi del genere, "avere ragione" si usa all'imperfetto indicativo (e quindi, congiuntivo). Se vuoi invece dire: «hai avuto ragione in quell'occasione particolare», puoi usare il congiuntivo passato, ma userei "penso" o "credo" nella principale («Credo che tu abbia avuto ragione in quell'occasione particolare»). Il problema, qui, più che l'uso del congiuntivo è la scelta tra imperfetto e passato prossimo.