# Dubbio sulla coniugazione dei tempi verbali in una frase

Tags: verbs

Ho un dubbio che mi sta mandando in pappa il cervello. In pratica ho formulato una frase per un mio articolo e nonostante la padronanza della lingua non riesco a capire quale sia la coniugazione corretta della stessa.

La frase è la seguente:

> **(1)** "Chiaro che se un prodotto risulti poco funzionale ai fini pratici per
> problemi di gameplay e di script ci sia qualcosa che non va e che
> potrebbe vanificare in maniera parziale o totale l’esperienza."

Io poi l'ho modificata così aggiungendo delle virgole che avevo mancato e invertendo due parole per far sì che foneticamente la frase suonasse meglio. Rimane però il problema dei tempi verbali.

> **(2)** "Chiaro che se un prodotto risultasse poco funzionale ai fini pratici,
> per problemi di script o di gameplay, ci sia qualcosa che non va e che
> potrebbe vanificare in maniera parziale o totale l’esperienza."

E ho tirato giù anche questa versione.

> **(3)** "Chiaro che se un prodotto risultasse poco funzionale ai fini pratici,
> per problemi di script o di gameplay, potrebbe esserci qualcosa che
> non va/vada e che vanificherebbe in maniera parziale o totale
> l’esperienza."

Mi interessa sapere se è corretto va o vada (o se sono sbagliate entrambe).

La mia fidanzata mi aveva suggerito invece questa modifica.

> **(4)** "Chiaro che se un prodotto risultasse poco funzionale ai fini pratici,
> per problemi di script o di gameplay, ci sarebbe qualcosa che non
> andrebbe e che potrebbe vanificare in maniera parziale o totale
> l’esperienza."

Ora, la domanda è: quale delle seguenti versioni della medesima frase è corretta grammaticalmente? Perché è quello che mi preme sapere in modo da non commettere errori la prossima volta, conoscendo la precisa regola grammaticale.

## Aggiornamento di @Isma92:

Grazie a tutti per le risposte, siete stati molto esaustivi. Prendendo in esame il modello (3) la potrei formulare anche così, volendo?

"Chiaro che se un prodotto risultasse poco funzionale ai fini pratici, per problemi di script o di gameplay, potrebbe esserci qualcosa che non vada e vanificherebbe in maniera parziale o totale l’esperienza."

Questo per non avere la ripetizione del "che".

Mentre così immagino non sia corretta. Dico bene?

"Chiaro che se un prodotto risultasse poco funzionale ai fini pratici, per problemi di script o di gameplay, ci sarebbe qualcosa che non va, vanificando così, in maniera parziale o totale, l’esperienza."

Scusate se non riesco a mettere le frasi nel quote o qualsiasi cosa sia che utilizzate voi. Sono da cellulare e non riesco a trovare la barra per applicare i vari codici.

Infine sul discorso della semplicità verissimo quanto dice DaG e in effetti suona benissimo mettendo tutto con l'indicativo. Tuttavia preferisco comunque mantenere in questo caso l'uso dei congiuntivi e condizionali poiché suonano meglio nel contesto del discorso.

Grazie ancora.

Comment: Troppi congiuntivi, troppi condizionali... È sbagliato ometterli dove servono, ma a volte li si usa gratuitamente. Con l'indicativo funziona tutto benissimo: “È chiaro che se un prodotto risulta poco funzionale ai fini pratici, per problemi di script o di gameplay, c'è qualcosa che non va e che può vanificare in maniera parziale o totale l’esperienza”.

Comment: @DaG Penso che il problema sia la scelta del periodo ipotetico della possibilità, piuttosto che quello della realtà (che come fai giustamente notare rende tutto molto scorrevole). Però una volta fatta questa scelta i tempi delle subordinate sono obbligati e a me un po' di congiuntivi qua e là non dispiacciono :)

Comment: Anche a me non dispiacciono, ma qui mi sembrano assordanti.

Answer (score 3):

Questa frase soffre di un abuso di congiuntivi e di condizionali. È sbagliato ometterli dove servono, ma a volte li si usa gratuitamente. Con l'indicativo qui funziona tutto benissimo:

> È chiaro che se un prodotto risulta poco funzionale ai fini pratici, per problemi di script o di gameplay, c'è qualcosa che non va e che può vanificare in maniera parziale o totale l’esperienza.

Consiglio la lettura di *La lingua è un'orchestra* di Mariarosa Bricchi, che tra l'altro si occupa della “congiuntivite”, intesa come eccessivo uso del congiuntivo con l'intento di elevare il tono del discorso, quando invece l'effetto risultante è il contrario.

Comment: +1, anche se va notato che l'uso dell'indicativo cambia leggermente il significato della frase. Probabilmente nel contesto presente non importa

Answer (score 1):

Questa è una classica frase formata da congiuntivo e condizionale.

Allora, (1) e (2) sono errate.
(1) perché si deve usare **se risultasse** e non **se risulti**.
(2) perché si deve usare **c'è** qualcosa che non va e non **ci sia**.

(3) è corretta usando **va** costruendola così (toglierei anche la e dopo va):

> "Chiaro che se un prodotto risultasse poco funzionale ai fini pratici,
>   per problemi di script o di gameplay, ci sarebbe qualcosa che
>   non **va**  che vanificherebbe in maniera parziale o totale
>   l’esperienza."

e con **vada** costruendola così, (anche qui toglierei anche la e dopo va):

> "Chiaro che se un prodotto risultasse poco funzionale ai fini pratici,
>   per problemi di script o di gameplay, potrebbe esserci qualcosa che
>   non **vada**  che vanificherebbe in maniera parziale o totale
>   l’esperienza."

(4) non mi sembra corretta solamente per quanto riguarda il fatto che è particolarmente contorta, la modificherei ricadendo nel caso (3).

Come al solito il miglior consiglio è la semplicità, come suggerisce correttamente @DaG:

> Con l'indicativo funziona tutto benissimo:
>
> “È chiaro che se un prodotto risulta poco funzionale ai fini pratici,
>   per problemi di script o di gameplay, c'è qualcosa che non va e che
>   può vanificare in maniera parziale o totale l’esperienza”.

Comment: Uhm, no qua *vada* è corretto (subordinata relativa che esprime una possibilità). Piuttosto *ci sarebbe qualcosa che non va*, senza il *potrebbe*.

Comment: Grazie, ho corretto la risposta

Answer (score 1):

Volendo conservare il tipo di periodo ipotetico, io sceglierei la seguente variante della versione (3)

> Chiaro che se un prodotto risultasse poco funzionale ai fini pratici, per problemi di script o di gameplay, potrebbe esserci qualcosa che non vada e che vanifichi in maniera parziale o totale l’esperienza.

Vediamo di fare un'analisi del periodo e di capire la scelta dei vari tempi e modi:

> **[È] Chiaro che** = proposizione principale, il verbo è all'indicativo presente
>
> **se un prodotto risultasse poco funzionale ai fini pratici, per problemi di script o di gameplay** = protasi di un periodo ipotetico della possibilità. Come spiegato in [questa mia risposta](https://italian.stackexchange.com/a/8164/1818), la protasi deve essere al congiuntivo imperfetto (*risultasse*)
>
> **potrebbe esserci qualcosa** = apodosi del periodo ipotetico precedente, come da regola va al condizionale presente (*potrebbe*)
>
> **che non vada** = proposizione relativa. Il modo da usare qui è il congiuntivo, poiché si tratta di una relativa che esprime una situazione ipotetica (cfr. *Dardano, Trifone* a pagina 469)
>
> **e che vanifichi in maniera parziale o totale l'esperienza**= un'altra relativa coordinata alla precedente, con cui concorda in tempo e modo.

Comment: Non mi è chiaro, nonostante la citazione dal Dardano-Trifone (e mi rivolgo anche ad @Abarisone che propone una formulazione simile), perché secondo voi quel “vada” debba andare al congiuntivo. Il tutto è contenuto in un periodo ipotetico, ma quella proposizione non ha in sé nulla di ipotetico. Cf. “una macchina che fa le tagliatelle”, “ho visto una macchina che fa le tagliatelle”, “potrei aver visto una macchina che fa le tagliatelle” (non “...che faccia le tagliatelle”). L'oggetto (la macchina che fa le tagliatelle) è sempre lo stesso, indipendentemente dalla frase in cui è inserito.

Comment: Mi sembra che lo stesso valga qui per “qualcosa che non va”, che ha lo stesso funzionamento sintattico di “una macchina che fa le tagliatelle”: come la macchina, il “qualcosa che non va” ha una sua autonomia sintattica, e il senso di eventualità dipende dal resto.